# Swipe-able tabs are not clickable when using Umano SlidingPannelUp Library

Tags: java, android

I've implemented Sliding Pannel Up Library. My main layout consists of a navigation drawer and swipe-able tabs view. After implementation of umano tabs couldn't be clicked.Also action bar icons too not recognizing touches. Means program not identifying any touch events in main layout.
Here's my activity_main file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start"
        >





       <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp"
    sothree:umanoParallaxOffset="100dp"
    sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
    sothree:umanoScrollableView="@+id/list">
           <FrameLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:orientation="vertical">
               <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:clickable="true">

               <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                       android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                       app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                       app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
                   <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                       android:id="@+id/tabs"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       app:tabMode="scrollable"
                       app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tabIndicatorColor"
                       app:tabGravity="fill"
                       android:clickable="true"
                       />
               </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
               </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
               <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
               android:id="@+id/viewpager"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
             app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
            </FrameLayout>
          <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:id="@+id/dragView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/follow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="Hello"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </ListView>


    </LinearLayout>


</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And my MainActivity

```
    package com.blackhole.socialmusic;
         import android.os.Bundle;
         import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
         import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
         import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
         import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
         import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
         import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
         import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
         import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
         import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
         import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
         import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
         import an droid.util.Log;
         import android.view.Menu;
         import android.view.MenuItem;
         import android.view.View;

         import com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout;
         import                     com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelSlideListener;
          import com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState;


           import com.blackhole.socialmusic.R;

            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.List;


           public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
         implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


            private static final String TAG = "DemoActivity";

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private SlidingUpPanelLayout mLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;



       mLayout = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);

       mLayout.addPanelSlideListener(new PanelSlideListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onPanelSlide, offset " + slideOffset);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelExpanded(View panel) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onPanelExpanded");

            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelCollapsed(View panel) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onPanelCollapsed");

            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelAnchored(View panel) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onPanelAnchored");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelHidden(View panel) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onPanelHidden");
            }
        });
        mLayout.setFadeOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mLayout.setPanelState(PanelState.COLLAPSED);
            }
        });

    }



    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new AlbumFragment(), "ALBUM");
        adapter.addFragment(new AlbumFragment(), "ARTIST");
        adapter.addFragment(new AlbumFragment(), "PLAYLIST");
        adapter.addFragment(new AlbumFragment(), "TRACKS");
        adapter.addFragment(new AlbumFragment(), "GENRES");
        adapter.addFragment(new AlbumFragment(), "FOLDERS");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (mLayout != null &&
                (mLayout.getPanelState() == PanelState.EXPANDED || mLayout.getPanelState() == PanelState.ANCHORED)) {
            mLayout.setPanelState(PanelState.COLLAPSED);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_toggle);
        if (mLayout != null) {
            if (mLayout.getPanelState() == PanelState.HIDDEN) {
                item.setTitle(R.string.action_show);
            } else {
                item.setTitle(R.string.action_hide);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_toggle: {
                if (mLayout != null) {
                    if (mLayout.getPanelState() != PanelState.HIDDEN) {
                        mLayout.setPanelState(PanelState.HIDDEN);
                        item.setTitle(R.string.action_show);
                    } else {
                        mLayout.setPanelState(PanelState.COLLAPSED);
                        item.setTitle(R.string.action_hide);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            case R.id.action_anchor: {
                if (mLayout != null) {
                    if (mLayout.getAnchorPoint() == 1.0f) {
                        mLayout.setAnchorPoint(0.7f);
                        mLayout.setPanelState(PanelState.ANCHORED);
                        item.setTitle(R.string.action_anchor_disable);
                    } else {
                        mLayout.setAnchorPoint(1.0f);
                        mLayout.setPanelState(PanelState.COLLAPSED);
                        item.setTitle(R.string.action_anchor_enable);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_feed) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_music) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_notification) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_setting) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably direct your question to the library maintainer by filing an issue on the Github page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm At last I've figured out the blunder mistake. The view pager covers the whole layout and touch events are passed yo it.
Just place the view pager inside coordinator layout and below tab layout.